# creating timeago with result from mysql fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, timeago

I have a script for converting a datetime value into a timeago. I have a php script that fetches the admin's message rows and time they were sent. However, i wish to convert this time to something like 20mins ago, hence i want to convert the time on each message to a certain time ago. So each time i add the timeago script into the mysql query, the page refuses to comeup. I guess the two script isnt working hand in hand.

This is my timeago script:

```
$ptime = "2017-06-08 03:16:20";
function get_timeago( $ptime )
{
    $estimate_time = time() - $ptime;

    if( $estimate_time < 1 )
    {
        return 'less than 1 second ago';
    }

    $condition = array( 
                12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
                24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
                60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
                60                      =>  'minute',
                1                       =>  'second'
    );

    foreach( $condition as $secs => $str )
    {
        $d = $estimate_time / $secs;

        if( $d >= 1 )
        {
            $r = round( $d );
            return ' This Happened About ' . $r . ' ' . $str . ( $r > 1 ? 's' : '' ) . ' ago';

            echo "$r";
        }
    }
}


$timeago=get_timeago(strtotime($ptime));
echo $timeago;
```

This is my mysql query:

```
 <?php
            $sql2="SELECT * FROM ".$cn."msg ";
            $result2= mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
                    while($rwsm=  mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
                  echo"<li>";
                    echo "<i class='fa  fa-envelope bg-orange'></i>";

                    echo "<div class='timeline-item'>";

                      echo "<span class=\"time\"><i class=\"fa fa-clock-o\"></i>".$rwsm[3]."</span>";

                      echo "<h3 class='timeline-header'><a href='mailto:".$rwsm[2]."'> ".$rwsm[2]." </a></h3>";


                      $msg= $rwsm[1];
                      echo "<div class='timeline-body'>".$msg."</div>";

                    echo "</div>";
                  echo "</li>";
                      }
                  ?>
```

This is where i tried to combine the both script to convert the `.$rwsm[3].` time variable to some time ago:

```
<?php
                   $sql2="SELECT * FROM ".$cn."msg ";
                $result2= mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
                        while($rwsm=  mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
                  echo"<li>";
                    echo "<i class='fa  fa-envelope bg-orange'></i>";

                    echo "<div class='timeline-item'>";

//THE TIMEAGO SCRIPT STARTS HERE                
$ptime = $rwsm[3];
function get_timeago( $ptime )
{
    $estimate_time = time() - $ptime;

    if( $estimate_time < 1 )
    {
        return 'less than 1 second ago';
    }

    $condition = array( 
                12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
                24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
                60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
                60                      =>  'minute',
                1                       =>  'second'
    );

    foreach( $condition as $secs => $str )
    {
        $d = $estimate_time / $secs;

        if( $d >= 1 )
        {
            $r = round( $d );
            return 'Last Updated: &nbsp; ' . $r . ' ' . $str . ( $r > 1 ? 's' : '' ) . ' ago';

            echo "$r";
        }
    }
}
$timeago=get_timeago(strtotime($ptime));
echo "<span class=\"time\"><i class=\"fa fa-clock-o\"></i>".$timeago."ago</span>";
//THE TIMEAGO SCRIPT ENDS HERE

    echo "<h3 class='timeline-header'><a href='mailto:".$rwsm[2]."'> ".$rwsm[2]." </a></h3>";

                      $msg= $rwsm[1];
                      echo "<div class='timeline-body'>".$msg."</div>";

                    echo "</div>";
                  echo "</li>";
                      }
                  ?>
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing? Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: @SloanThrasher The page refuses to comeup, it shows just blank white but when i remove the timeago script the page loads properly displaying the messages and date but without the timeago.

Comment: Are you saying error reporting is turned on? I don't see it in the files.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Sorry there isnt any error reporting on the file.

Comment: Turn it on. Hard to know what's going wrong if you can't see the problem.

Comment: Add these two lines: ```error_reporting(E_ALL);``` 
```ini_set('display_errors', '1');```

Comment: @SloanThrasher where do i add this line: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` on the file?

Comment: At the beginning of the script - right after <?php

Comment: @SloanThrasher i just did but it still displays nothing on the page when i run the script.

Comment: You can use a try{}catch(){} statement. to find on which line is error.

Comment: @AsimZaka Please how do i do that using the code above?

Comment: If try catch does not work you can debug code line by line.
use die("Write some thing"); check your page by putting it line after line in your code.

Comment: @Harryson Danie have look at this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp